# Disable Wordpress limit for duplicated user email

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a very big multisite. And I got a request to enable option that multiple users can use the same email. I found a plugin "Allow Multiple Accounts" which doesn't work properly. I should figure out some other solution for that. I know that I could use something like adding +sometext to every email, so it will show different to Wordpress. Do you have some other solution, that can be done here?

Comment: I do not understand what your request is. What do you mean by "use the same email"?

Comment: multiple users on one email

Comment: that means, that I need to be able to register multiple users with same email address.

Comment: I guess there isn't a way to deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the multisite architecture, users can be shared beetween websites of network. 
One user can be assigned to multiple sites.
Can the user sharing solve your problem?

Comment: No, because I need to be able to register multiple users with one single email address.

Answer (score 0):

There's a plug in called allow allow-multiple-accounts. Fair warning it hasn't been updated for more than two years but it just might work.